# java.lang.Exception: Font name not found in Android Mobile

Tags: javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I use Gluon with JavaFX and JAVAFXPORTS. The App Works in Desktop fine. But in Android , I have this Error. It is like a Font Name is not found. But i don't know exactly which Font.

Somebody can help please

```
java.lang.Exception: Font name not found.
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFile.init(PrismFontFile.java:533) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFile.(PrismFontFile.java:103) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFontFile.(FTFontFile.java:57) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory.createFontFile(FTFactory.java:75) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.createFontResource(PrismFontFactory.java:273) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.createFontResource(PrismFontFactory.java:260) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.populateFontFileNameMapGeneric(PrismFontFactory.java:1883) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(PrismFontFactory.java:1776) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getFontResource(PrismFontFactory.java:469) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getSlot0Resource(LogicalFont.java:194) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getDefaultAAMode(LogicalFont.java:409) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getStrike(LogicalFont.java:413) 
 at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFont.getStrike(PrismFont.java:73) 
 at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.setContent(PrismTextLayout.java:138) 
 at javafx.scene.text.Text.getTextLayout(Text.java:229) 
 at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Text.java:184) 
 at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Text.java:95) 
 at javafx.scene.text.Text$2.invalidated(Text.java:389) 
 at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:109) 
 at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144) 
 at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49) 
 at javafx.scene.text.Text.setText(Text.java:370) 
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils.computeClippedWrappedText(Utils.java:375) 
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateDisplayedText(LabeledSkinBase.java:466) 
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.layoutLabelInArea(LabeledSkinBase.java:932) 
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.layoutLabelInArea(LabeledSkinBase.java:857) 
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.layoutChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:841) 
 at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:575) 
 at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1079) 
 at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085) 
 at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085) 
 at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085) 
 at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085) 
 at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552) 
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2401) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:348) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.access$lambda$3(Toolkit.java) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source) 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:347) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:374) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:503) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$387(QuantumToolkit.java:321) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.access$lambda$2(QuantumToolkit.java) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.enterNestedEventLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:107) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(MonocleApplication.java:144) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107) 
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:598) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.a(SourceFile:613) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.access$lambda$4(SourceFile) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog$$Lambda$5.changed(Unknown Source) 
 at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181) 
 at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80) 
 at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:178) 
 at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.access$100(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:148) 
 at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:144) 
 at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110) 
 at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.access$000(BooleanPropertyBase.java:49) 
 at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:245) 
 at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:348) 
 at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80) 
 at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103) 
 at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110) 
 at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer.setShowing(SourceFile:108) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.a(SourceFile:601) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.access$lambda$6(SourceFile) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication$$Lambda$8.accept(Unknown Source) 
 at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:154) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.showLayer(SourceFile:592) 
 at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.showAndWait(SourceFile:564) 
 at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.d.c.b(SourceFile:77) 
 at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.d.c.access$lambda$0(SourceFile) 
 at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.d.c$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source) 
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295) 
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java) 
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source) 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52) 
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294) 
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java) 
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92) 
 at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: If you are adding some font to your desktop app, notice that it might not be available on your phone. One way to be sure is adding the font file as resource, and loading the font, on both desktop and android font. By default, Gluon library includes `Roboto` font. Try using this font.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks for the Answers. I don't add another font. I search everywhere in my Code and in the FXML File. There is not font that i have add.

Comment: That is the Repository Project available on Github. https://github.com/allipierre/CAMVOYAGE

Comment: I remember, that I had a similar kind of issue, but don't longer know, how I resolved it. And it was in the early days of JavaFXPorts... BTW: Why did you not change the default package structure of you app? And the Android package name? Have you never tried to run the app on a phone, before you've developed so much already?

Comment: @JoséPereda Can you guide how i can resolve this Problem? I mention that, i don't add any Font.

Comment: I've managed to deploy your app, and run it on my Android device. I don't see this exception. Which is your Android device/version? One thing I had to change: all the FXML views should go in lower letters, like `suchefahrt.fxml`.

Comment: @jose Pereda. Thanks for answer. I use android version 5.0.1 model GT-L9515

Comment: And do you still get the font exception? Did you update the fxml files name?

Comment: Yes . It works fine . The exeption is go. It works fine. I update the fxml files. Thank